# How to check if the input is a username or an email when user log in based on the input and given password?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to allow the login input to be either username & password or email & password. How do I use the javascript function to tell whether the input is a username or an email? 
I am using vanilla js so no jquery or PHP, thanks!

`vanilla js`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Use string validation to check if the user login input is email or not, this is all what I can suggest since you didn't provide code.

Answer (score 2):

Call this function on submit

```
function validate() {
        var login = document.getElementById('field').value;

        // Check if email
        if (/\@/.test(login)) {
           //its email address 
           // your code goes here
        }
        else {
            //its username 
           // your code goes here
        }
}
```